# Trying to sign into Sandbox Apple ID in Settings leads to "User name or password is incorrect."

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to add In App Purchases to my app so I set up a sandbox Apple ID with one of those myemail+test01@domain.com types of emails. I also copied the password from Notes straight into App Store Connect, so it's definitely not messed up there.

I got the verification email, I verified, then I tried signing the Apple ID into the simulator using my app. I typed in the details at the point where the fields in that alert comes up, I press ok, then nothing. The box disappears and nothing comes up. I tap the button again, then the Apple ID prompt shows up again.

Then I tried it in Settings by going to "Sign in with your Apple ID" and typed in my Apple ID & password in there, and I got a message saying "User name or password is incorrect."

I tried setting up another sandbox account with a different password format, got that verified, then the same thing happened.

How do I get this working correctly and sign in properly? I obviously need to test these things before I launch.

Comment: Did you follow this process - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_with_sandbox ? Once you have successfully signed in in your app with a sandbox tester, you will see a new sign in option in the App Store settings.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm having trouble understanding the documentation. Is it saying I need to sign in using my normal developer Apple ID I use to access App Store Connect?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I fixed it by logging into iCloud.com once using the sandbox account, then signing into the iPhone simulator.

(I tried accepting this answer, but it won't let me for 2 days :/)

Comment: I can't believe that was necessary. But it worked...thanks!

Comment: wtf can't believe this was it. Dum azz error message.